# How to read only the last lines by the time ID of an excel file in Pandas to perform calculations for them and write them to a separate file

Tags: python, pandas

I am constantly downloading data from the DDE server of another program, which is then transferred to my Python application.

The DEE server transfers them to an excel file

They look something like this:

| Time | Value | Qty | V | Operation | OI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10:00:00 | 19320 | 3 | 57960 | UP | 187686 |
| 10:00:00 | 19325 | 2 | 57255 | UP | 187623 |
| 10:00:00 | 19326 | 10 | 57960 | UP | 187425 |
| 10:00:00 | 19310 | 5 | 57960 | Down | 187222 |
| 10:00:00 | 19355 | 2 | 57960 | Down | 187432 |
| 10:00:01 | 19333 | 1 | 57960 | UP | 187552 |
| 10:00:01 | 19310 | 5 | 57960 | Down | 187123 |
| 10:00:01 | 19312 | 2 | 57960 | UP | 188123 |
| 10:00:01 | 19344 | 9 | 57960 | Down | 188822 |

I run a lot of functions with a while loop and run my calculations with it

```
def Convert():
    b = 1
    while a == True:
        tic = time.perf_counter()
        Read_exel()
        Poc()
        Tik()
        Ct()
        Delta_By_Sel_Second()
        Open()
        Volume()
        Pmm()
        P_last()
        Comulativ_delta()
        Data_with_Oi()
        print('The cycle has been completed', b, 'times')
        print(" ")
        b = b+1
        toc = time.perf_counter()
        print(f"The calculation took {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
        time.sleep(10)
```

For example, here are a few of my functions

```
def Read_exel():
    Exel = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(Ex))
    Exel.to_csv (Ex_Csv,
        index = False,
        header=True)


def Volume():
    A = ["S","T", "5T", "10T" ]
    for a in A:
            df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(Ex_Csv,  usecols=["Time", 'Qty'], parse_dates=[0]))
            df['Time'] = df['Time'].dt.floor(a, 0).dt.time
            #print(df)
            b = df.groupby('Time').agg('sum')
            if a == "S":
                b.to_csv(V_second)
            elif a == "T":
                b.to_csv(V_min)
            elif a == "5T":
                b.to_csv(V_Five)
            else:
                b.to_csv(V_Ten)
```

Everything is read by the Read_excel() function and written to csv, and then all the other calculations come from this csv file

Because of this, with each new iteration of the while loop, all files are overwritten in a new way

Is there any way to make excel read only the latest data with the latest time identifier, that is, if the last time in exel was 12:00:13, then he wrote all the rows with this identifier in csv

Comment: Considering subslicing the excel, `Exel[Exel['Time'] == Exel['Time'].max()]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Read_Ex():
    Exel = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(Ex))
    Exel['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(Exel['Time']).dt.time
    A = Exel[Exel['Time'] == Exel['Time'].max()]
    A.to_csv (Ex_Csv,
        index = False,
        header=True)
```